# Thinking-Sphinx with ActsAsTaggableOn tags search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, thinking-sphinx, acts-as-taggable-on

I have a Rails app in which I use `Thinking-Sphinx` for search and `ActsAsTaggableOn` for tagging. I want to be able to include the currently selected tag in my search query. I have tried the following but not got it to work.

In my controller:

```
def show

  @team_tags = @team.ideas.tag_counts_on(:tags)

  if params[:tag]
    @ideas = @team.ideas.search(params[:search], :conditions => { tags: "tag" })
  else
    @ideas = @team.ideas.search(params[:search])
  end

end
```

My index for my `Idea` model:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :idea, :with => :real_time do
  [...]
  indexes tags.name, :as => :tags

  has user_id, type: :integer
  has team_id, type: :integer
  [...]
end
```

This gives me he following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (index idea_core: query error: no field 'tags' found in schema
```

When I have a tag selected my `URLs` looks like this:

```
/teams/1/tags/tag
```

So, what should I do to get `Thinking-Sphinx` and `ActsAsTaggableOn` to work together?

Comment: Did you used rake ts:start and rake ts:index   http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/quickstart.html

Comment: @ThanatosSama Yes, I have done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've got for your field will only work with SQL-backed indices, not real-time indices.

In your case, what you want to do is create a method in your model that returns all the tag names as a single string:

```
def tag_names
  tags.collect(&:name).join(' ')
end
```

And then you can refer to that in your index definition:

```
indexes tag_names, :as => :tags
```

Once you've done that, you'll need to regenerate your Sphinx indices, as you've changed the structure: `rake ts:regenerate`.

Comment: does that really work? from Thinking Sphinx docs (http://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/indexing.html): "You cannot reference model methods - Sphinx talks directly to your database, and Ruby doesn’t get loaded at this point."

Comment: @Miotsu the docs are referring to SQL-backed indices (using `:with => :active_record`), but the index in the question here is using real-time indices (`:with => :real_time`), and in that case you can *only* reference model methods.